# How to create a native file in react-native on iOS?

Tags: ios, file, react-native

How can I create a native file on iOS?

For Android on react-native, it looks like [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) will work.

Has anyone found a react-native component for iOS to create and write files?

My goal is to send an email with attachment. The project [react-native-mail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mail) is a great react-native component to send email including file attachments that supports ***both*** Android and iOS.

I just need to figure out how to do file I/O in react-native.  Else I need to learn how to write my a [react-native iOS Native Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) to perform file I/O.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mail

Thanks in advance for any direction,

Comment: react-native-fs has support for ios also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a database of 3rd party modules: https://js.coach/

Through it I found the same module you did. It looks like it has iOS support too?
https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs

Comment: You are right it supports iOS and Android.  I guess I only saw the Android folder.  However It clearly discusses both iOS and Android in the readme.MD.  I do not know what I was thinking.  Thank you.  And thank for posting the link to https://js.coach/  resource.

Comment: https://js.coach/ will save me much time since it supports a react-native search category!  I have wasted hours searching through results on https://www.npmjs.com/ by keywords trying to find react-native modules.  https://js.coach/  even indicates Android and/or iOS in the search results. Thank you *very* much!